# How change language of DatePicker (months and days)?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, datepicker

How change language of DatePicker (months and days) in Material UI?

I tried implement localization by theme and LocalizationProvider. Locally either globally way doesn't work. https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/localization/ [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6ySI.png)

I use typescript and MUI v6.5.0

Comment: You should add code here to be able to help you 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example provided by [the link](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/localization/) you provide only explains how set the localization for the MUI component.

The dates are being generated by [dayjs](https://day.js.org/). You can use `adapterLocale` to set the localization of the adapter. If you set that property you'll need to import the **associated locale** from `dayjs`.

In the following example I used Dutch, but you can swap it out for what you want to use.

```js
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { nlNL } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/locales";

import 'dayjs/locale/nl';

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider
      dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
      adapterLocale="nl"
      localeText={
        nlNL.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText
      }
    >
      <DatePicker views={['month']} />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```